# FLUTTER:- BlocBuilder or a separate stateful Widget

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, open-source

Just a question I had while looking into enhancing the performance of a flutter app I have been working on.

Lets say I have a screen in which I have different widgets to be displayed lets name these widgets as heroWidget and each heroWidget has the option to change its colour and text and the screen will be having 21 of such  heroWidgets.

To implement this I have done the following :-

1. Wrote a helper function for a heroWidget which will have a drop down allowing the user to choose the option to change colour, or write any text.
2. Used the flutter_bloc package and have written a bloc to handle colorChangeEvent and textWriteEvent !!.
3. Wrapped a BlocBuilder on top of the heroWidget (in the helper function). This BlocBuilder will be listening to the colorChangeState or the textWriteState with respective index value to which of the 21 heroWidgets to build and based on that will call the builder method to build the widget with the new values.
4. Use a ListView.builder to build the list of the different 21 heroWidgets.

My Question is...I am using 21 BlocBuilders for 21 heroWidgets will this effect the performance of the app !?.

Will the performance improve if I make a single heroWidget as a Statefull Widget and then update the state..using setState than have 21 separate BlocBuilders !!

Answer (score 0):

First, "enhancing performance"... ask yourself if you have issues. If not, consider if it is premature optimization.

The short answer is probably: No, it will not effect the apps performance.

It does not sound like a user will notice any performance degradation based due to your few BlocBuilders in this scenario. If you have any performance problems, I wouldn't suspect the use of BlocBuilders. Rather what is done other than that. I've got hundreds of BlocBuilders in a view without any issues.

My suggestion to you is to not worry about performance until it is a proven problem. Make sure your solution is readable, testable and maintainable. That is more important aspects to consider.

Comment: Thank you Robert for answering my question and Thank you for the suggestion it does makes sense what you have written. But I am coming across the issue of the app crashing at times on certain low end android devices, and I was just wondering if it could be because of the BlocBuilders. Also there are images being used so each heroWidget will also be having images (which yes could be something that does occupy more memory when the app is running). But I am not sure if the images is the only problem here !

Comment: You'd have to profile it to see the whats and whys... But I'd be very very surprised if it is the actual BlocBuilders and BlocListeners is the problem. You can also configure those using e.g. the "buildWhen"-property to only rebuild on certain conditions. That could improve rebuilds a lot as well.